# Text Location on Custom Visio 2010 Master Shape

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I am creating a new master shape and would like the text (when user pressesto be placed above the shape and not in the middle.  How can that be configured?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To accomplish this task, you need to control the *Text Block* of the shape. The good news is that you have a lot of control over this in Visio.

First, select the **Text Block tool** (highlighted below) on the **Home** tab of the Ribbon to get started.

[image]

The instructions are for using the tool are [here at the  online documentation for Visio 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/add-edit-move-or-rotate-text-and-text-blocks-HA010357412.aspx).

Also, to get the text block working perfectly when shapes are resized you'll need to set the **Text Transform** section in the ShapeSheet to achieve your desired outcome. The Text transform section controls the size and positioning of the text block.

The **Text Transform** section is shown below

[image]

Additional resources:

- [Top Twelve Text Tips](http://www.visguy.com/2009/05/06/top-twelve-text-tips/) by the Visio Guy (May 6, 2008)

Comment: Visio is completly broken why something so simple have to be so complicated

Comment: On Visio 2022, text transform is much easier. The same button but you can drag the text to go!